# CGAL hole filling with color

Tags: cgal, libigl

I need to implement a 3D hole filling using CGAL library that support color.

is there any possibility to do it without CGAL library modification? I need to fill the hole with an average color of the hole's edge.

Regards, Ali

```
....

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  const char* filename = (argc > 1) ? argv[1] : "data/mech-holes-shark.off";


  Mesh mesh;
  OpenMesh::IO::read_mesh(mesh, filename);

  // Incrementally fill the holes
  unsigned int nb_holes = 0;
  BOOST_FOREACH(halfedge_descriptor h, halfedges(mesh))
  {
    if(CGAL::is_border(h,mesh))
    {
      std::vector<face_descriptor>  patch_facets;
      std::vector<vertex_descriptor> patch_vertices;
      bool success = CGAL::cpp11::get<0>(
        CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing::triangulate_refine_and_fair_hole(
                  mesh,
                  h,
                  std::back_inserter(patch_facets),
                  std::back_inserter(patch_vertices),
     CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing::parameters::vertex_point_map(get(CGAL::vertex_point, mesh)).
                  geom_traits(Kernel())) );

      CGAL_assertion(CGAL::is_valid_polygon_mesh(mesh));

      std::cout << "* FILL HOLE NUMBER " << ++nb_holes << std::endl;
      std::cout << "  Number of facets in constructed patch: " << patch_facets.size() << std::endl;
      std::cout << "  Number of vertices in constructed patch: " << patch_vertices.size() << std::endl;
      std::cout << "  Is fairing successful: " << success << std::endl;
    }
  }

  CGAL_assertion(CGAL::is_valid_polygon_mesh(mesh));

    OpenMesh::IO::write_mesh(mesh, "filled_OM.off");
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use CGAL::Surface_mesh as Mesh, you can use dynamic property maps to define attributes for your simplices, which allows for example to define colors per face. The "standard" syntax for this is

```
mesh.add_property_map<face_descriptor, CGAL::Color >("f:color")
```

I think. There are examples in [the documentation of Surface_mesh](https://cgal.geometryfactory.com/CGAL/Manual_doxygen_test/CGAL-4.12.1-I-248/output2/Surface_mesh/index.html#sectionSurfaceMesh_properties).